# Writing a text file to smart card c#

Tags: c#, smartcard

What I want to do is write a text file to a smart card and read it.
WindSCard is the dll to be used but but it's functions are very cryptic.
Is there any FREE wrapper available over it and is there any tutorial that does what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

- What card do you use
- Are you sure you can write to the card?
- Do you have the APDU manual for the card?

After you find a basic example of SCard* you need to know the right APDU-s to send to the card with SCardTransmit

Comment: It is a CHIP CARD READER.......PS/SC Here is the link to it http://www.m-techindia.com/html/chipcard_reader.php

Comment: The card is PS/SC.Please let me know if u know how to write a text file.

Comment: PC/SC is an API for accessing smart card readers (and through smart card readers, sending data - APDU-s - to cards).

When PC/SC calls for communicating with readers does not differ from reader to reader, the APDU-s that need to be sent to the card differ from card to card.

Comment: Can u tell me the about the method for card which is most frequently used ?